# How can i detect if the mail which i sent has been opened, and in which browser (user agent), and OS using PHP?

Tags: php, email, user-agent

in my company we use to send mails, and we want to have a static of opened mails and from which browser they were opened( more informations as possible) using PHP.

Comment: You can't do this. Because all major mail services doesn't support JavaScript for security reasons.

Comment: But if i use php?

Comment: Why would you need all that information?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding image in your HTML email

```
<img src="https://example.com/images/YOUR_LOGO__uc_12245.png" />
```

But this url https://example.com/images/YOUR_LOGO__uc_12245.png must be handled by your scripts (PHP) where you can check headers of request and at the end just return requested image as normal. Some services do that way. In **uc_12245** you can store id of your user, for example.

But remember, this is will not work every time, for example with Gmail, because Gmail show your image via proxy (*it needs to be tested, maybe it still will work*).

Comment: `you cant store id of your user` - I'm sure you meant `you can store` :)